# Is it possible to look up a table-valued function's return columns in SAP HANA's dictionary views?

Tags: hana

I've created a table-valued function in SAP HANA:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_tables
RETURNS TABLE (
    column_value INTEGER
)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT 1 column_value FROM SYS.DUMMY;
END
```

Now I'd like to be able to discover the function's table type using the dictionary views. I can run this query here:

```
select * 
from function_parameters 
where schema_name = '[xxxxxxxxxx]' 
and function_name = 'F_TABLES'
order by function_name, position;
```

Which will yield something like:

```
PARAMETER_NAME         TABLE_TYPE_SCHEMA    TABLE_TYPE_NAME
---------------------------------------------------------------------
_SYS_SS2_RETURN_VAR_   [xxxxxxxxxx]         _SYS_SS_TBL_[yyyyyyy]_RET
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to be able to look up that `_SYS_SS_TBL_[yyyyyyy]_RET` table in `SYS.TABLES` (and `TABLE_COLUMNS`), `SYS.VIEWS` (and `VIEW_COLUMNS`), `SYS.DATA_TYPES`, etc. in order to find the definitions of the individual columns.

Note that explicitly named table types created using `CREATE TYPE ...` do appear in `SYS.TABLES`...

Is there any way for me to look formally look up a table-valued function's return columns? I'm not interested in parsing the source, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of tables are internal row-store tables, therefore you can only find your `_SYS_SS_TBL_[yyyyyyy]_RET` table in `SYS.RS_TABLES_`. This will give you some basic information, including a column ID (`CID`). This value is important to find the column information.

For example, if your CID is 100, you can find column information in the `RS_COLUMNS_` table with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.RS_COLUMNS_ WHERE CID = 100
```

Comment: Problem here is that SYS objects are not officially supported and require special permissions.

Comment: That may be true but it is also the only way to obtain the desired information. Plus, the original question suggests that he has access to the SYS schema

Comment: @Lars: Are you sure about the *"not officially supported"* part? I mean [they are all documented](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/cbb10c75191014b47ba845bfe499fe/content.htm?frameset=/en/2e/1ef8b4f4554739959886e55d4c127b/frameset.htm), and I would imagine that the dictionary views are the only way for any tool (e.g. ERDs, or in our case, [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)) to discover metadata. To me, this not only implies official support but also backwards-compatible API evolution... How else would you discover metadata?

Comment: I think @Lars might have referred to the RS_TABLES_ and RS_COLUMNS_ tables. Those do not appear in any documentation because they are internal tables. The monitoring views in SYS on the other hand (SYS.M_*) are specifically created to retrieve metadata about the HANA objects. It just happens that the kind of table you are looking for is "highly internal" and therefore only appears in those undocumented tables

Comment: @TimoD: I actually do not have any access to that table, and if it is internal, I prefer not to access it at all. But why do tables created with `CREATE TYPE` get listed in `SYS.TABLES` but not these implicitly created types? Do you know that?

Comment: @LukasEder I have no idea, sorry.